# Replace the epsilon and delta in the definition of continuity, what kind of continuity do we get?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

1) $f : X \to Y$ is a map. For all $x_0\in X$, if for every $\delta > 0$, there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $d_X(x_0, x) < \delta$ whenever $d_Y(f(x_0), f(x)) < \varepsilon$.

2)$f : X \to Y$ is a map. For all $x_0\in X$, if for every $ \varepsilon> 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $d_Y(f(x_0), f(x)) < \delta$ whenever $d_X(x_0, x) < \varepsilon$.

Is map $f$ continuous in the two cases? If not, what kind of continuity is this?

For the second the case, I guess this definition is much stronger than continuity?

Comment: You have shown that $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(x_0)$ (if it exists at all) instead of showing that $f$ is continuous at $x_0.$

Comment: The function is bounded in the second case

Comment: What is the context where you have found such a weird looking questions?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Due to my humble love of math

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331445/the-epsilon-delta-definition-of-continuity?rq=1)

Comment: Every bounded function is continuous according to definition 2). So you cannot call it a form of continuity.